# Grid errors when compiling Sass

Tags: css, visual-studio-code, sass, grid

```css
@media (min-width: 40em) {
  .article__grid {
    -ms-grid-columns: (1fr)[2];
        grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  }
}

@media (min-width: 64em) {
  .article__grid {
    -ms-grid-columns: (1fr)[4];
        grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
  }
}
```

When I start this project I didn't know how to use gulp, and instead I use the live SASS compiler;

but when I was trying to use the Grid layout on my project the vs code start telling me that the
CSS output has some problems , but even with that the result on my browser(chrome) was perfect. so my question here is " is there any problem with this code because when I checked the sass compiler I found out that the last update was in 2018."

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3CNV0.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am facing this same problem, but I use **CSS specificity ( !important )**  & its works in my case. But implementing it in your **.scss** file, hope it works for you.

```
@media (max-width: 1000px) {
   main {
     grid-template-columns: repeat(1, 1fr) !important;
   } 
}
```